# Django send email alerts automatically when keywords matches to his profile

Tags: django

Send an email alert whenever newly created profile matches to his search term. I have two module recruiter and seeker. Recruiter can posted their jobs and Seeker can posted their profile. If recruiter searches the seeker's profile based on city name, keyskills,industry type etc.. The searched result can be saved because for future use. If any new seeker's profile matches that searched result which is saved previously it automatically send email to recruiter. This alert has been send everytime when new seeker can matched that recruiter search terms.

***Recruiter table***

```
class jobs(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobsummary = models.TextField()
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    functionalarea = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    min_exp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    max_exp = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class employerkeyskills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    job=models.ForeignKey(jobs, unique=False)
    keyskills=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class RecSaveSearch(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    employer=models.ForeignKey(User,unique=False)
    searchname=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    savedsearch=models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
```

***Jobseeker Profile Table***

```
class JSPersonal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    work_expyears = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    work_expmonths = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    salaryrange = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class JSSkills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    lastused = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    skillyear = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    skillmon = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Use signals after creation of a Seeker profile. Check for profile data and send emails if necessary.

Comment: Definitely use post-save signals.